# Upgrade from 22.10 to 23.04 broke NIC

Tags: networking, kernel, ethernet

I've got a Dell Optiplex Mini 3080, with an internal NIC and an external USB 3.0 NIC.
After upgrading from Ubuntu 22.10 (Kernel 5.19.0-46) to Ubuntu 23.04 (Kernel 6.2.0-33), my internal PCI NIC stopped working.
I am getting tons of:

```
r8169: rtl_ephyar_cond == 1 (loop: 100, delay: 10) 
r8169: rtl_eiar_cond == 1 (loop: 100, delay: 100)
```

I tried adding `pcie_aspm=off` to my grub, but that did not help. Right now I'm using the old kernel. When the machine boots up, everything works fine for a few moments, after that, the NIC stops working.

lspci output is as follows:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 10th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] (rev 05)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-V USB Controller
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-V Thermal Subsystem
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-V HECI Controller
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 400 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #21 (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #05 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation B460 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Power Management Controller
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-V cAVS
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-V SMBus Host Controller
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron/Crucial Technology P2 NVMe PCIe SSD (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

I've also tried `r8168-dkms` but I might have done something wrong, because it didn't even detect my NIC.
Could you please advise?

Comment: There have been bugs in the Realtek driver that caused the connection to be lost whenever the driver went into power save mode. You may want to read [this discussion](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=107421), especially [the last suggestion](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=107421#c44) to download a driver from Realtek

Comment: What is the output of `sudo lshw -C network`?  Also the output of `dkms status`. Please add that to your question.